# unhandled error when trying to run rethinkdb-poll-demo on windows

Tags: windows, rethinkdb

I've tried to follow the instructions on [RethinkDB for Windows: developer preview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klgE2Jo5beE) youtube video, which uses the code from Github https://github.com/segphault/rethinkdb-poll-demo.  RethinkDB runs as expected on localhost:8080, but when I tried to run app.js from the rethink-poll-demo directory by entering 'node app' in the command prompt, I get an error message after "Creating a pool connected to local host:28015 
       events.js:141   throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
       Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:8000"

I haven't changed any code, am new to both node.js and rethinkDB.  Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: check if port 8000 being is used: netstat -an | find "8000"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another process binding to port 8000.
Check it by running: `netstat -an`

Comment: Thankyou port 8000 was being used

Comment: I changed line 43 in app.js - 'server.listen(8000)' replacing 8000 with 3000, and the poll-demo now works on localhost:3000